# Redirect to Action by parameter mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to redirect to an action in other Controller but it doesn't work
here's my code in ProductManagerController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RedirectToImages(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index","ProductImageManeger", new   { id=id   });
}
```

and this in my ProductImageManagerController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index(int id)
{
    return View("Index",_db.ProductImages.Where(rs=>rs.ProductId == id).ToList());
}
```

**It redirect to ProductImageManager/Index without parameter very well(no error)** but with above code i get this:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for
>   parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index(Int32)' in
>   '...Controllers.ProductImageManagerController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Comment: RedirectToImages cannot redirect to ProductImageManager/Index because of invalid parameter order

Comment: @jim I have just one parameter,id, so what parameter order mean here?

Comment: Need `"Index", "ProductImageManager"` instead of `"ProductImageManager","Index"`

Comment: how does `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` method body looks like? Add it to message

Comment: @jim in redirect Url i get  /ProductManager/Index instead of /ProductManager/Index/1 , why my parameter doesn't send?

Comment: You error message says "ID", not "id" parameter. Looks like this error occurs in another action.

Comment: I think got it. i have registered "{controller}/{action}" instead of "{controller}/{action}/{id}". sorry! thank you so much

Comment: Ok, then please accept my brilliant answer broken by some guy :)

Comment: sure, write your correct answer :)

Comment: it's already below for long time :)

Comment: @Mohammadreza would you consider accepting my answer? Or perhaps add a better answer that can be accepted?

Answer (score 22):

This error is very non-descriptive but the key here is that **'ID'** is in uppercase. This indicates that the route has not been correctly set up. To let the application handle URLs with an id, you need to make sure that there's at least one route configured for it. You do this in the **RouteConfig.cs** located in the **App_Start** folder. The most common is to add the id as an optional parameter to the default route.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //adding the {id} and setting is as optional so that you do not need to use it for every action
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now you should be able to redirect to your controller the way you have set it up.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RedirectToImages(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index","ProductImageManager", new { id });

    //if the action is in the same controller, you can omit the controller:
    //RedirectToAction("Index", new { id });
}
```

In one or two occassions way back I ran into some issues by normal redirect and had to resort to doing it by passing a *RouteValueDictionary*. More information on [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300844/2960852)

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new RouteValueDictionary( 
    new { controller = "ProductImageManager", action = "Index", id = id } ) 
);
```

If you get a very similar error but in lowercase **'id'**, this is usually because the route expects an id parameter that has not been provided (calling a route without the id `/ProductImageManager/Index`). See [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052813/the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-id-of-non-nullab) for more information.

Comment: dear @Binke their not same. productManger, and productImageManger. my mistake was in configuring in routConfig. i mention it in Question's comment. any way tnx for your help :)

Comment: You can simply use RedirectToAction for this. No need of route value dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

This should work!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RedirectToImages(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProductImageManeger", new  { id = id });
}

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index(int id)
{
    return View(_db.ProductImages.Where(rs => rs.ProductId == id).ToList());
}
```

Notice that you don't have to pass the name of view if you are returning the same view as implemented by the action.

Your view should inherit the model as this:

```
@model <Your class name>
```

You can then access your model in view as:

```
@Model.<property_name>
```

Comment: No, The problem is at routing ProductImageManagerController Index Action.

Comment: Can you paste your app.routes code here as a part of question? Because it works. Not sure why you downvoted!

Answer (score -2):

```
return RedirectToAction("ProductImageManager","Index", new   { id=id   });
```

Here is an invalid parameters order, should be an action first
**AND**
ensure your routing table is correct

Comment: And that does no good. Fix your answer and I get rid of my downvote.

Comment: LOL, you crack me up.

Comment: dear @jim It without parameter redirect to ProductImageManager/Index . I'm confuse.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionEventName", "Controller", new { ID = model.ID, SiteID = model.SiteID });
```

Here i mention you are pass multiple values or model also. 
That's why here i mention that.

Comment: Where did the `SiteID` come from?