# mvc 5 RedirectToAction does not return View, stays on the same browser page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I stumbled on an error when I tried to redirect a user to another view here:

```
public IActionResult Edit([FromBody]int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("EditProduct", "Admin", new { id = id});
}
```

After that the view should be generated:

```
public IActionResult EditProduct(int? id)
{
    var Products = _repository.GetProduct(id);

    return View(Products);
}
```

In result the redirect gets into EditProduct View but in the browser it stays in the same page. Am I doing something wrong or is there an exception I do not know about?

Comment: How do you call "Edit"?

Comment: `EditProduct` is part of the `Admin` controller right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to Action by parameter mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929990/redirect-to-action-by-parameter-mvc)

Comment: As @Liam asked, can we see where the action is called from?  Is it from the razor view?

Comment: Action is called from js file. 
$http.post("/Product/EditProduct", productId);

Yes, EditProduct is part of admin controller.

Comment: MVC does not redirects using an ajax call. As an workaround you can use window.location on your page.

Comment: But you can not pass an identificator via window.location. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

As Suman Pathak said in comments MVC does not do redirects using an ajax call. So i passed identificator via js file:

```
 window.location = "/Admin/EditProduct/" + productId;
```