# MVC 4 Page not working after altering Html.beginform()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I had been using this line at the top of my edit.cshtml page:

`@using (Html.BeginForm())`

but then I changed it to:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

and now when I hit submit on that page I try to run this method:

`public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "description,tags,files,fileString")] Task task, int keyId, string editFiles)`

I get this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'keyId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Combined.Models.Task, Int32,
>   System.String)' in 'Combined.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters    Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters
>   dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'keyId' of non-nullable
>   type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Edit(Combined.Models.Task, Int32, System.String)' in
>   'Combined.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I tried changing the line to:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", keyId = Model.keyId }))`

but it didn't make any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are using wrong overload actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add KeyId to the form as a hidden input instead of in the route parameters, since you are posting.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.keyId)
```

(Actually, you are adding it as an Html Attribute. View source on your page and look where it is being rendered.)

Comment: I tried @Html.HiddenForm(model => model.keyId) (which is something I saw in another SO post) but VS cant seem to find the method. Is that not the right way to do that?

Comment: Not sure if it was a typo in your comment, but it should be HiddenFor. (not HiddenForm)

Comment: Nope wasn't a typo, maybe it was a typo in the other post. I was so close!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ehsan-sajjad, in my case I was using the wrong overload and your comment helped me.

This is what worked, putting the id after the controller and before the form method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new { keyId = Model.keyId }, FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: This should be in the comments rather than added as another answer, please consider moving it as it may be helpful to some, but it is not an answer.