# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I keep getting this error passed to me when I submit an edit.  I've tried a few different tactics like adding `int?` or sending the id's through the url, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32)' in 'XXX.Controllers.OBProfileTaskFieldsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>
> Parameter name: parameters

I have my controller that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, int tid, OBProfileTaskFields fieldToUpdate)
    {
        try
        {
            OBProfileTaskFields originalField = this.dbContext.OBProfileTaskFields.FirstOrDefault(obptf => obptf.ProfileID == fieldToUpdate.ProfileID && obptf.TaskID == fieldToUpdate.TaskID && obptf.FName == fieldToUpdate.FName);
            originalField.FRequired = fieldToUpdate.FRequired;
            originalField.FLocked = fieldToUpdate.FLocked;
            originalField.CCAccess = fieldToUpdate.CCAccess;
            originalField.EEAccess = fieldToUpdate.EEAccess;
            if (originalField.SeqNbr != fieldToUpdate.SeqNbr) ReorderProfileTaskFields(fieldToUpdate.ProfileID, fieldToUpdate.TaskID, fieldToUpdate.FName, (int)fieldToUpdate.SeqNbr);
            originalField.SeqNbr = fieldToUpdate.SeqNbr;
            this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "OBProfileTasks", new { id = originalField.ProfileID});
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(this.dbContext.OBProfileTaskFields.FirstOrDefault(obptf => obptf.ProfileID == fieldToUpdate.ProfileID && obptf.TaskID == fieldToUpdate.TaskID && obptf.FName == fieldToUpdate.FName));
        }
    }
```

and my view is like this:

```
<!--Modals-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="instructions-@item.TaskID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="instructionsLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="instructionsLabel">Instructions</h4>
                                </div>
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "OBProfileTaskFields", FormMethod.Post))
                                {
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.ProfileID"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="tid" value="@item.TaskID" />
                                        <p>Placeholder text for isntructions or anything of that sort.</p>
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.CCInstruction, new {@class = "form-control", @rows = "6", @style = "width: 80%;"})
                                        <p>Placeholder text for isntructions or anything of that sort.</p>
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.EEInstruction, new {@class = "form-control", @rows = "6", @style = "width: 80%;"})
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                }

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am passing the two different IDs that i assume I need.

Comment: How are you passing the Ids ? This question looks similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052813/the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-id-of-non-nullab.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the error here: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "OBProfileTasks", new { id = originalField.ProfileID});`
You pass only 1 parameter while the error says that Index requires 2 (`Index(Int32, Int32)`)

Answer (score 1):

Here it's seems that the method Index required 2 parameters so you have to redirect with 2 paramters like`

```
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "OBProfileTasks", new { id = originalField.ProfileID, tid = 2});
```

Here we i choose tid= 2