# Api Controller Routing error - the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two httpGet methods in my api controller. I use attribute routing to differentiate between them.
When I navigate to localHost/api/Lockers/availableLockers
I get an error:

> the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetLocker(Int32)

**In my Lockers api Controller:**

```
 public IQueryable<Locker> GetLocker()
        {
            return db.Lockers;
        }


        [Route("availableLockers")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Locker> GetAvailableLockers()
        {
            return db.Lockers.Where(l => l.StudentId != null);
        }

[ResponseType(typeof(Locker))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLocker(int id)
    {
        Locker locker = db.Lockers.Find(id);
        if (locker == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(locker);
    }
```

***What I tried:***

Based on a previous [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052813/the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-id-of-non-nullab) I added to my webAp.config

**In webApi.config**

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SecondApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
```

This does not change the error

Comment: The message states it executing a `GetLocker` method (which you have not shown). And you state your url is `localHost/Lockers/availableLockers` but that does not contain `/api/` in the route

Comment: Also you need to put specific route configuration before the default route configuration.

Comment: Visit this for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: I can see 3 actionmethods in your above code. And to call these three as per your code routes will be like: 1. localhost/api/lockers 2. localhost/api/lockers/availableLockers 3. localhost/api/lockers/1

Comment: @ankit sahrawat. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add RoutePrefix attribute on your controller as below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Lockers")]
public class LockersController : ApiController
{

}
```

After adding RoutePrefix on your controller your route: localHost/api/Lockers/availableLockers will start working. Currently it is throwing exception because application is considering it as id=applicationLockers which expects last parameter as int

Answer (score 0):

It was your routing attribute. It should have been:

```
    [Route("api/Lockers/availableLockers")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Locker> GetAvailableLockers()
    {
        return db.Lockers.Where(l => l.StudentId != null);
    }
```